# How do I create a datetime field in a cython struct? How about a string field?

Tags: python, cython

How do I create a datetime field in a cython struct:

```
cdef struct Purchase:
    int purchase_id
    datetime purchase_timestamp
    str free_text
```

What should I use to represent the "datetime" identifier above?

What about for a string? Would I just use a "char*" Is there something more flexible? If I delete an instance of the Purchase class, do I have to do any memory cleanup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from cpython.datetime cimport datetime

cdef class Purchase:
    cdef int purchase_id
    cdef datetime timestamp
    cdef str free_text
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Answer (score 1):

That is not a class, it is a C data structure. It only accepts C types.

Have a look at documentation for [extension types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) (classes).

Eg:

```
cdef class Purchase:
    cdef int purchase_id
    cdef timestamp
    cdef str free_text
```

Comment: thanks! Is there a cython-optimized type for datetime objects?

Comment: @danny I don't think `cdef datetime timestamp` will work, since `datetime` is only known at runtime. You'd just do `cdef timestamp` to allow any Python object. @vgoklani Internally these things are all just stored as integers (e.g. unix `time_t` or numpy/pandas `datetime64`)